# What are these "portholes & panels" on the fuselage of the Omega Tanker DC-10?

Tags: feature-identification, dc-10

If you take a look at the photo (source: still from [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfpoilhfwNc)), you'll notice a pair of "panels" on the fuselage of this Omega Tanker DC-10 (reg: N974VV), circled with green.

There is also a pair of "portholes" (circled red).

What are all those? Any relation to this being a tanker?

*Note: [Here's a photo](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Omega-Tanker/McDonnell-Douglas-DC-10-40/4144899/L?qsp=eJwtjcEKwjAQRP9lz15EUeytfoB6kN6XzVADsQmbLVhK/901eBvePGZWkjwZPvZcCqijClZ50Y4KK78rdSspxlhN2WKeerGZk3u3y/k4DO7VrHZdnAQ29CIohvDndw3QX4UqbXL0i70H6KNlOpych1hL4rYB45ho275PyzI2) that shows the "panels" closed on the ground.*

[image: Omega Tanker]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The things circled in red are **static ports**. They are used to measure static air pressure. You can see a close up (from a different aircraft) here:

[image: Static Ports]
<sup>(taken from [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22137/what-steps-have-been-taken-to-rule-out-instrument-failure-due-to-blocked-static/37875#37875))</sup>

What you circled in green is an **outflow valve** used for controlling the pressurization. See also:

- [What is this device below the door of a 737 (and other aircraft)?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24776/what-is-this-device-below-the-door-of-a-737-and-other-aircraft)
- [How does the outflow valve work on a cabin pressurization system?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/44639/how-does-the-outflow-valve-work-on-a-cabin-pressurization-system)
- [How does a DC-10 flight engineer manually raise the cabin altitude?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/73756/how-does-a-dc-10-flight-engineer-manually-raise-the-cabin-altitude)

It is technically called a **Thrust Recovery Outflow Valve**:

> The actual nomenclature is the "Thrust Recovery Outflow Valve"
>
> [...]
>
> The thrust recovery outflow valve is essentially the valve that controls cabin altitude throughout the isobaric selection range. It can be controlled electrically through 2 electric motors receiving input from the automatic and semi-automatic cabin pressure controller/computer. On the -10's with Flight Engineers, the clutches could be disengaged via a handle at the FE station, and the valve was then controlled through a manual wheel.

<sup>([Airliners.net](https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=724969))</sup>

Both items are unrelated to the fact that this is a tanker. The following image shows the same items on a Northwest Airlines DC-10-40:

[image: Northwest Airliners DC-10-40]
<sup>([Airliners.net](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Northwest-Airlines/McDonnell-Douglas-DC-10-40/154370/L))</sup>